# How do I compare two lists and return a list with elements that share the same index?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to take a user input of 4 digits, compare it to a randomly generated 4 digit number, and then return the values they have in common in the same indices.

So for example:
Secret number: 4667

User input: 3608

Output: _ 6 _ _

Unfortunately, when I run what I've written already, it prints the digits in whatever position they're in on the secret number regardless of their position in the user input, and then it also returns a number of "_" for each iteration in the `for` loop.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from random import randint

def randomNumber():
    numberList = []
    digits = 0
    while digits != 4:
        numberList += [randint(0,9)]
        digits += 1
    return numberList

secretNumber = randomNumber()

guessNumber = list(input("Enter a four digit number: "))

guessNumber = list(map(int, guessNumber))

guessList = guessNumber.copy()
correctNumbers = []
numberPosition = []
numberPosition.clear()
for number in guessNumber:
    if number in secretNumber:
        correctNumbers.append(number)
        for n in secretNumber:
            if n == number:
                numberPosition.append(n)
            else:
                numberPosition.append("_")
```

I apologize if there's any spacing/tabbing issues with this code block, I copied it over from a Jupyter notebook.

Thanks!

Comment: You are comparing each ``number`` to *each* guessed number, not just the one at the same position.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I need to return the guessed numbers that are in the random number but aren't in the same position, and also return the guessed numbers that are in a the random number and in the matching index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the iteration logic is somewhat incorrect. Considering the example -

```py
In [10]: secretNumber = [4,6,6,7]

In [11]: guessNumber = [3,6,0,8]

In [12]: for i in range(len(secretNumber)):
    ...:     if secretNumber[i] == guessNumber[i]:
    ...:         numberPositions.append(secretNumber[i])
    ...:     else:
    ...:         numberPositions.append("_")
    ...:

In [13]: numberPositions
Out[13]: ['_', 6, '_', '_']
```

You basically need to iterate only once for the length of either lists (4 in this case) and update the `numberPositions` variable.

Here's a oneliner of the above code if you are interested -

```py
In [12]: "".join([str(secretNumber[i]) if secretNumber[i] == guessNumber[i] else "_" for i in range(len(secretNumber))])
Out[12]: '_6__'
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! That first `for` loop is actually keeping the correct numbers the user guesses, and then I also needed to return the position of the correct numbers they guessed. This works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def f(a, b):
    for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))):
        if a[i] == b[i]:
            yield i, a[i]
        else:
            yield i, None

a, b = '123456', '2335678'
print(''.join(['_' if c is None else c for _, c in f(a, b)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one-line code will do it:

```
In [1]: ''.join(a if a==b else '_' for a, b in zip(secretNumber,guessNumber))
Out[1]: '_6__'
```